# Sorting a ListView by tag in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

I have a list view with some columns `listViewItems`. When I use the Sort method `listViewItems.Sort();` it sorts by column text by default. This is the code I use:

```
private void OnColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int sortColumn = 0; --I only want to sort if you click this column header, not others
            if (e.Column == sortColumn)
            {
                if (listViewItems.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    listViewItems.Sorting = SortOrder.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    listViewItems.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
                }
            }
            listViewItems.Sort();
```

However, my items have a Tag, accessible by `listViewItems[0].Tag;`

I would like to use that tag to sort the list (in my case tag is an int), but I don't know how to do it nor find information about something similar. Sort method doesn't accept any parameters. I tried to create a column sorter, but it also expects a column.

```
ListViewColumnSorter lvwColumnSorter;
lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
listViewItems.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = ?;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Tag,listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Tag);`

Answer (score 4):

```
var items = ListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().OrderBy(x => x.Tag).ToList();
ListView.Items.Clear();
ListView.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

Comment: "Property ListView.Items cannot be assigned to -- it is read-only."
And it seems to be something internal, I cannot change it to not read-only.

Comment: Regarding the second part, after the = I get "ListView.ListViewItemCollection does not contain a definition for OrderBy" and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type ListView.ListViewItemCollection".

Comment: it will have if you cast it as ListViewItem. have a lookk at answer.

Comment: Yeah, now with the cast that works but not the addrange. It says: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem> to System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[].

Comment: just add `.ToArray()` have look at answer.